# Exclude marker from clustering - Google Maps Extension (Android app)

Tags: android, maps, android-maps-extensions

I'm using version 1.3.1 of the Google Maps Extension and am trying to exclude a marker from being clustered.  I have one marker that is set in the onCreate method of my app and it represents My Location.  I want this to always be visible and not be clustered like the rest of my markers.  Is this possible?  I tried adding the marker before I set the clustering settings and before I called setClustering on the GoogleMaps object, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using just one `Marker` which should not be clustered with all other, you can see a workaround in comment #2 here:

https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/issues/detail?id=10#c2

Basically using `SupportMapFragment.getMap().addMarker(...)` instead of `SupportMapFragment.getExtendedMap()`

The problem is you will get null in `GoogleMap` callbacks like `onMarkerClick`, but for just one `Marker` you can find out it's "the Marker". Clustering engine will not be aware of `Marker` added that way.
You will also have class name collision, so you have to use full class name for original library like `com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker` in case you keep a reference to this `Marker`.

Hope it helps until this improvement is implemented.

**Edit:**

This is available as of version 1.5 via simple call:

```
theMarker.setClusterGroup(777);
```

The default group is `0` and only `Marker`s with the same group are clustered together, so if you change one `Marker`'s group, you'll get the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, however I have many markers on the map.

Comment: @PhilipBischof I meant if you have one marker you don't want to be clustered.

Comment: If you set the marker's cluster group to a negative number, it will never be clustered: marker.setClusterGroup(ClusterGroup.NOT_CLUSTERED); or map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).clusterGroup(ClusterGroup.NOT_CLUSTERED));

Comment: Thanks @silver_man. I wrote this answer before negative cluster group was implemented. You can edit the answer to add this info.